Class conversion operator is not called implicitly
In the program below, class A has a convert-to-int operator. Class B has a convert-to-A operator. While the compiler converts A to int implicitly, it fails to do so for converting B to A:
class A
{
protected:
    int _a{0};
public:
    A(int a) : _a(a) {}
    operator int() const {return _a;}
    A operator-(const A& rhs) const {return _a - rhs._a;}
};

class B
{
protected:
    int _b{0};
public:
    B(int b) : _b(b) {}
    operator A() const {return _b;}
};

int main()
{
    A a(1);
    B b(2);
    auto x = 2 - a;  // Ok
    auto y = b - a;  // error: no match for ‘operator-’ (operand types are ‘B’ and ‘A’)
    return 0;
}

Why does it behave like this?

b - a is going to look for an operator - with B being the first parameter.  You don't have one so the compiler goes no further.

a - b would work.

Re: "A has a cast-to-int operator" -- it has a convert-to-int operator. "the compiler casts A to int implicitly" -- the compiler converts A to int implicitly. A cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion; it cannot be implicit.

Keep in mind that b - a is sugar for b.operator-(a), and the compiler won't do a static_cast<A const&>(b).operator-(a) conversion for you.

friend A operator-(const A& lhs, const A& rhs) would allow to be symmetrical... But then 2 - a would be ambiguous (int - int or A - A).

implicit conversions are a mess. The right fix here would be to make your conversion explicit and call static_cast<A>(b) - a; if you want that

@PeteBecker Thanks for the hint. I edited the question according to your comment.

using wrong wording in a question is just natural, no need to fix imho. It doesnt hurt of course, but you missed the title, and an answer refers to the questions initial wording. If you edit to fix the wording I'd drop a comment on that answer, so it can be fixed too

@463035818_is_not_an_ai I generally agree. But since the OP did fix the wording I completed the task by updating the title (and removed the obsolete note from my answer).

User-defined conversions on the implicit object parameter of a function are explicitly not allowed in overload resolution.
Because your operator- is defined as member of the class, the left-hand side of - is the implicit object parameter. No attempt will be made to use a user-defined conversion on the argument/operand provided for it, your conversion function from B to A being such a user-defined conversion.
For what it is worth, the built-in - is considered in overload resolution as if there were free operator- overloads taking corresponding built-in types as parameter, which is why there user-defined conversions are permitted on both sides of - and the built-in operator-(int, int) overload is viable for 2 - a.
If you implement your operator- as a free function outside the class, it will work as you expect.

The expression b - a, is in this case actually a syntactic sugar for b.operator-(a).
The compiler will looks for operator- in class B, will not find one, and issue an error.
If you invert the order to a - b it would work:
It will be equivalent to: a.operator-(b).
A does have an operator-, which requires another A. Here the compiler will use the conversion operator from B to A and it will compile.
You can solve this by implementing operator- as a free function outside the class, which will make it symetrical.
